# How do I tokenize a text file

Tags: r, nlp, data-science

I am trying to perform text analytics on the following text [file](https://www.kaggle.com/kingburrito666/shakespeare-plays/downloads/alllines.txt/4). The code I have written to tokenize this text after importing it is:

```
my_data <- read.delim("5KjlUO.txt")
library(tokenizers)
library(SnowballC)
tokenize_words(my_data$ACT.I)
tokenize_words(my_data)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in check_input(x) :    Input must be a character vector of any
>   length or a list of character   vectors, each of which has a length of
>   1.

Can someone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please tag your programming language ([tag:r]?), so people who have experience with it will be alerted to your question; and also note that we prefer any text to be actually text, not images.

Comment: Make your text available outside of kaggle. Not everyone has an account / wants to go through the hassle of downloading the file from kaggle. Check this post on how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What does `class(my_data$ACT.I)` return? Are you sure it's a character vector. If you used `read.delim()` like that it's probably a factor variable. Try tokenize_words(as.character(my_data$ACT.I))`.